# Virtual method with unspecialized template argument

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, template-specialization

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

// Currently I have code much like this one:

template <const uint32_t N>
using VectorN = array<double, N>;


template <const uint32_t N>
class ITransformable {
public:
    virtual vector<VectorN<N>>&  positions() = 0;
};


class SomeTransformer {
public:
    template <const uint32_t N>
    void operator()(ITransformable<N>& transformable) const {
        /* implementation */
    }
};

// Then I want to create interface like this.

template <const uint32_t N>
class ITransformer {
public:
    virtual void operator()(ITransformable<N>& transformable) const = 0;
};

// And finally implement it for SomeTransformer:
// 
// Notice that class is not template, this is intentional.
//
// class SomeTransformer : public ITransformer<N> {
// public:
//     virtual void operator()(ITransformable<N>& transformable) const {
//         /* implementation */
//     }    
// }
```

Actually, now it seems impossible to me. Otherwise this class would inherit
indefinite number of interface specializations...

But still, is it possible, at least for finite number of dimensions *N*?

`template <template <typename> class C>` seems to be related, but I can't figure out how to apply this.

**EDIT**
What I want is something like this:

```
class SomeTransformer : 
    public ITransformer<2>, 
    public ITransformer<3>, 
    public ITransformer<4>, 
    ..., 
    public ITransformer<N> { 
    /* ... */ 
};
```

For any **N** ever used in code. This seems impossible, as I said.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors yet. I can't even figure out syntax for this.

Comment: You mean for commented part?

Comment: Yes. Everything else compiles and works flawlessly.

Comment: is ```template<uint32_t N> class SomeTransformer: public ITransformer<N>``` something you're after? i.e. your concrete SomeTransformer needs to be a template class, and you just pass the template parameter onto its based class ITransformer<N>

Comment: @SPD , nope. Roughly speaking, I want something like `class SomeTransformer : public ITransformer<2>, public ITransformer<3>, public ITransformer<4>, ..., public ITransformer<N> { /* ... */ };`.

Comment: @L117 hmm, so N is a runtime variable you don't know at compile time then? Then I think you need vector instead of array in this case.

Comment: It looks a bit strange that you want a class with N functions that all like quite similar. Is it really necessary to have N be part of the function signature? Could it also be a function parameter?

Comment: Deriving from all the instances will increase the size without the use of all the functions I believe. In general the design seems to be broken... The underlying use case is unclear to me! If each transformer has N and only derives from ITTransformer<n> it is ok, but not to derive from all... only my suggestion as I don't understand the given problem!

Comment: @Klaus Actually, yes, you ARE right. Now, when I heard it and tried to explain what I want, I can see clearly that design IS broken. It makes much more sense to have `template` transformers, as well as other classes generic over N. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you want or nearly that. Here's what I propose:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template<std::size_t N>
struct ITransformer {};

template<class T>
class SomeTransformer_h { };

template<std::size_t... Indices>
class SomeTransformer_h<
    std::integer_sequence<std::size_t, Indices...>> :  
    public ITransformer<1 + Indices>... { };


template<std::size_t N>
class SomeTransformer : public SomeTransformer_h<
    std::make_index_sequence<N>
> { };

int main() {
    SomeTransformer<5> a;
    ITransformer<1>& ref = a;
    ITransformer<4>& ref2 = a;
    ITransformer<5>& ref3 = a;
}
```

Now for any `N` it will make `SomeTransformer` inherit all `ITransformer` from 1 to N.

Answer (score 1):

Since `N` is not declared anywhere, you cannot use it. You need something like:

```cpp
class SomeTransformer : public ITransformer<5> {
public:
    virtual void operator()(ITransformable<5>& transformable) const {
        /* implementation */
    }    
};
```

or make it a template class:

```cpp
template <uint32_t N>
class SomeTransformer : public ITransformer<N> {
public:
    virtual void operator()(ITransformable<N>& transformable) const {
        /* implementation */
    }    
};
```

**UPDATE**

There is **no dynamic inheritance** in C++. Therefore, what you want to achieve is not possible.

Comment: Yep, I'm aware of these. I've edited question, hope now it's more clear what I want.

Comment: In the end, declaring transformers as templates is the right solution. What I initially wanted is nonsense.